# What does this code using typeof … != "undefined" and clearInterval do?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, undefined

For school I need to write a game in JavaScript but the problem is I don't understand what this part of code means:

```
if (typeof game_loop != "undefined") clearInterval(game_loop);
    game_loop = setInterval(paint, 60);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `if (typeof game_loop != 'undefined')`

if the variable `game_loop` is not `undefined`

> `clearInterval(game_loop);`

clear the existing interval whose id is `game_loop`

> `game_loop = setInterval(paint, 60);`

call `paint` every `60` milliseconds and store the interval id in `game_loop`.

---

Ideally for clarity the code would be written as:

```
if (game_loop !== undefined) {
    clearInterval(game_loop);
}
game_loop = setInterval(paint, 60);
```

`typeof xyz !== 'undefined'` is used to avoid a possible bug when `window.undefined` is overridden, but no one should ever override `window.undefined`, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: But if I do: if (typeof game_loop != "undefined"){ clearInterval(game_loop); } else {
        game_loop = setInterval(paint, 60);
        } it doesn't work?

Comment: @StuiterSlurf, `game_loop = setInterval(...);` must always be called. It's not an `else` condition.

Comment: "if the variable `game_loop` is `undefined`" - you probably mean is *not* `undefined`.

Comment: `if(game_loop !== undefined)` will return an error if `game_loop` hasn't been declared.  If it *has* been declared but it's undefined, there's no harm in calling `clearInterval` on it.

Comment: @RickHitchcock, always use `"use strict"` and you'll never need to worry about such things.

Comment: True, my point is that the `if` check in your "Ideally" code throws an error if `game_loop` *isn't* declared, and it isn't needed if `game_loop` *is* declared.

Answer (score 0):

If `game_loop` exists, than stops the timer.

After this, sets the timer to execute `paint` every 60 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

It is checking if `game_loop` exists, if it does, clears the interval.  Then, it makes a `paint` call every 60ms.